# Связь нескольких моделей

Tags: javascript, extjs

Привет.

> Фреймворк Ext JS 4 три подобных
> отношения или типа связей:
>
> Один ко многим (One-to-many) (тип Ext.data.HasManyAssociation)
>
> Многие к одному (Many-to-one) (тип Ext.data.BelongsToAssociation)
>
> Один к одному (Has-one) (тип Ext.data.association.HasOne)

У меня вопрос зачем такой механизм и чем его суть?И в чем отличния между ними?
Это хранение внутри объекта свойтсв другого объекта ?

Answer (score 2):

Это нужно просто для создания связи между различными моделями, чтобы моделями было легче манипулировать и управлять. И у каждой ассоциативной связи там своя специфика. Подробнее можете посмотреть тут: [Связь нескольких моделей](http://metanit.com/web/extjs/12.4.php)